# NullPointerException error by running scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I installed Scala and spark on my laptop and afterwards, I set scala environment on Intellij. As you can see in the image below, I am receiving this error "NullPointerException" by running the code. Do you have any advice how to fix it? I appreciate your help so much.
Best!
[image]

Comment: What is in `pom.xml`? Do you have Java installed? What do you mean by "setting scala environment on Intellij"? Did you install Scala plugin for Intellij? Did you try to build your project with Maven (since you have `pom.xml`) without IntelliJ? Did you try sbt? What is in `Run configuration`? https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea-for-scala.html

Comment: Did you try to use [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) ? if you have sbt, you can create new sbt project by calling `sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8` (https://github.com/scala/scala-seed.g8). Try to open this project in Idea and run it (1st via `sbt run`, then, if everithing is ok, via IDE),

Comment: Report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with a sample project and full textual output of the error and idea.log file.